# Scroll to previous/next command in tmux window

Tags: bash, terminal, tmux, scrolling

I know how to scroll ,page up or page down in tmux, but I want command or key combination using which I can directly jump to prev/next bash command in my tmux window.

For example, Suppose I did `ls -lrt` then did some `cat file.txt`, now how can I directly go to line where `ls -lrt` command was typed in tmux window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your shell prompt is unique, you could bind a key to search-backward for it, something like:

```
bind -Tcopy-mode C-x send -X search-backward "user@host:"
```

Then use C-x to jump between shell prompts in copy mode.

Or this to allow entering copy mode first:

```
bind -Tcopy-mode C-x send -X search-backward "user@host:"
bind C-x copy-mode \; send -X search-backward "user@host:"
```